# krunner Browser Tabs, is there a way to narrow search results to specific category?

Tags: kde

in krunner, I would like to search results within only one category. Especially "browser tabs".

Is there any keyword or search query to achieve that?

example query which I would love to have it working:

```
browsertabs:slack
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I searched some internet and found one answer [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KRunner#Switch_active_windows)

However it doesn't give you "out of the box" solution to narrow results "on the fly" in default krunner popup. But it's sufficient enough.

To open the krunner in narrowed search popup:

1. open default terminal in linux
2. paste below command and run (in terminal not in krunner!):

```
qdbus org.kde.krunner /App querySingleRunner browsertabs "slack"
```

3. that opens krunner with narrowed search to browser tabs.

you can bind this command with a key in system settings > custom shortcuts
than you just use shortkeys to directly open narrowed ppopup without need to open terminal.

To display “narrow search popup” without default query, remove “slack”.

Ps.: tip. in combination with xdotool you can send enter to automatically go to slack tab or sth.